# Entity Framework cannot bind value object in entity constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've created an entity that takes a value object as a parameter in it's constructor, however when I add the entity to the db context it throws the following exception.

> InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type >'BasketItem'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be >bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'price' in >'BasketItem(Guid id, Guid productId, DateTimeOffset addedAt, Money price)'.

I've tried `builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Price);` in the type configuration. Keep in mind that I am using the in memory storage provider.

BasketItem.cs

```cs
public sealed class BasketItem : Entity
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset AddedAt { get; private set; }
    public Money Price { get; private set; }

    public BasketItem(Guid id, Guid productId, DateTimeOffset addedAt, Money price) : base(id)
    {
        ProductId = productId;
        AddedAt = addedAt;
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

Money.cs

```cs
public sealed class Money : ValueObject
{
    public decimal Value { get; private set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; private set; }

    public Money(decimal value, string currencyCode)
    {
        Value = value;
        CurrencyCode = currencyCode;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
    {
        return new object[] { Value, CurrencyCode };
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing price from the constructor, and make it not private. It's likely that owned entities cannot be constructor parameters of the parent entity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Implementing DDD *value objects* with EF Core [owned entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) has several shortcomings, caused by the fact that EF Core owned entity types are still considered **entities**, and properties returning owned entity types are treated as **navigation properties**.

In this particular case, the issue is caused by the last aforementioned thing along with the following [Entity Type Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors) limitation

> Some things to note:
>
> - EF Core cannot set navigation properties (such as Blog or Posts above) using a constructor.

The workaround / solution is to provide special private constructor to be used by EF:

```
public BasketItem(Guid id, Guid productId, DateTimeOffset addedAt, Money price) : this(id, productId, addedAt)
{
    Price = price;
}

/// <summary>
/// EF constructor
/// </summary>
private BasketItem(Guid id, Guid productId, DateTimeOffset addedAt) : base(id)
{
    ProductId = productId;
    AddedAt = addedAt;
}
```

And of course use `[Owned]` attribute or `OwnsOne` fluent API to map `Money` as owned entity type.

Comment: There has been work done around owned types and value objects in past few versions. Is the limitation that owned types are treated as navigation properties still the case in v5 and v6? (In v5 you still can't put the value object in the ctor, but maybe there is some new workaround.)

Comment: @lonix You can do some tests and verify that. From what I know, the limitation is still there. Also the docs still shows *EF Core cannot set navigation properties (such as Blog or Posts above) using a constructor*. And yes, these are still entities, hence references to them are navigation properties. May be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#value-objects will change that for value objects in EFC 7.0, at the end of the year :)

Comment: Yes I saw that, but funnily enough nowhere does it explicitly say that "owned types are treated as navigation properties", that would be important to note in the owned types docs (I'm gonna put a request in the repo for that). The only place I found that info is this answer of yours, as usual. I think they should let you write the docs from now on! :)

Comment: @lonix He-he, with my bad English this would be terrible idea :) They just need to start writing more explicitly some things which I guess they think are "obvious". Or you have to jump to another topics to find them. In this case, the key is the word **entity** (owned or not). Then in [Definitions of Terms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#definition-of-terms) for Relationships you can see *"Navigation property: A property defined on the principal and/or dependent entity that references the related entity."*

Comment: I put a [docs update](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/3723) request thanks to your advice. And please don't underrate your English, it is excellent. I wish to master other languages as well as that.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if that is still relevant, I had a similar issue with EF today.
What actually helped me was adding an empty constructor** to my class:

```
public MyClass()
{}
```

Afterward, everything worked as intended and the database was successfully updated.

Comment: This would work but you're defeating the point of defensive programming.

Comment: I agree with @Ionix, in DDD programming you never implement an empty public constructor in your entities. From my PoV Ivan's approach is safer.